# Internet Explorer 9 - proxy exceptions not working

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, exception, proxy

After I've upgraded from IE 8 to IE 9, all the proxy exeptions stopped working - when I try to ping ceratain IP, I get the response, but when using http protocol the request gets timeout. I define the exceptions like that:

```
171.22.192.155:9090;171.22.230.102
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try 171.22.192.155;171.22.230.102;